# Explanation Of Storage of an image on a machine

Tags: image, storage, pixel, binary-image

I want to know that **how the storage of an image is determined** (the size of an image is determined). i have read some articles but some say that **1 pixel = 1 byte** (which according to me should be wrong) and some says it takes **32 bits for high depth image colors**. Can somebody explain me how the storage of an image on a machine works?

Comment: It's just like anything else. Instead of storing it is as a matrix, it is stored as a vector. The header of the image contains information like type of image (color, grayscale), dimensions, rows, coloumns, etc. 1 pixel = 1byte for grayscale images, 1 pixel = 32 bit for colored images (r,g,b,alpha). The alignment of bits may differ in little endian and big endian machines (just like any other storage).

Comment: thanks for your reply but i want to ask that i know vector is way better than raster graphics but does vector take more memory on disk or not? and how does the header contains dimensions?

Comment: Yes, raster graphic image files are larger than vector graphics image files. See this: http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/raster-graphics. How the dimensions are stored in header depends on the image format, now there are many of those, I cannot comment (don't know) about the specifics.